British film, country boy moves to London to sign band
I'm trying to recommend a movie I watched last year but can't remember the name for the life of me.  The plotline basically goes:

Slightly dim-witted guy who lives in a British small town believes a London underground band is the next big thing.
He moves to London with his girlfriend.
They eventually get the band to sign.
Despite the bands lack of professionalism, they catch the eye of competing record companies.
In the end the band signs with another manager.
Guy moves back to the country, glad he accomplished what he set out to do (get the band to be big), despite not getting to stay on with them.


If you mean the film is from last year, you probably mean Svengali from 2013. From Wiki:

Svengali tells the story of Dixie (Jonny Owen), a postman from South Wales, and a music fanatic. All his life he's dreamed of discovering a great band and then one day, trawling through YouTube, he finds them... 'The Premature Congratulations'. He hunts them down and offers them his management services. [...] Putting their demo on a cassette tape, Dixie heads out onto the streets of London [...] The more successful The Prems get, the greater the chances are of Dixie losing them.

The film is based on a Youtube series by the same name. Here's the trailer:



